# How to repaint the progressbar in FMX (Android)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, rad-studio

I have a progress bar and a lot of tasks to do. I just want to increase the value of the progress bar when a task (bool and void functions) was completed. For example:

```
changeClothes();
progressBar1->Value = 20;
eatSandwich();
progressBar1->Value = 40;
if(isWeekend()){ 
 progressBar1->Value = 60;
 ShowMessage("Weekend!");
}else
 ShowMessage("Not Weekend");
haveDinner();
 progressBar1->Value = 80;
timeToSleep();
 progressBar1->Value = 100;
```

I tried to do using a `for` but no good results. Tried to do in the way that I mentioned,  but it does everything and shows the bar already with the `value` in 100.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    ProgressBar1->Value = i;
    Sleep(50);
    Application->ProcessMessages();
}
```

Although, it is recommended that you don't call `ProcessMessages` very often as it will slow down the application. Maybe like this would be better:

```
    if(!(i % 10))
        Application->ProcessMessages();
```

In your case try it like this:

```
    changeClothes();
    progressBar1->Value = 20;
    Application->ProcessMessages();
    eatSandwich();
    progressBar1->Value = 40;
    Application->ProcessMessages();
    if(isWeekend()){ 
     progressBar1->Value = 60;
     Application->ProcessMessages();
     ShowMessage("Weekend!");
    }else
     ShowMessage("Not Weekend");
    haveDinner();
     progressBar1->Value = 80;
     Application->ProcessMessages();
    timeToSleep();
     progressBar1->Value = 100;
     Application->ProcessMessages();
```

Comment: Not working, I can't put `for` in the whole code. `ProcessMessages()` not work for this too. I just need a way to "task done? So + 20(or 30, 40, just an example) in the value of `ProgressBar`, wait for 1 second and go to the another".

Comment: After you increase the value (position) of the `ProgressBar1` you need to call `ProcessMessages()` and that's it. That will make sure the position of the progress bar is updated at that very moment.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, like you show above, but no good results. I think the solution is not a `for`, just a function or something to stop for some milliseconds `(sleep())` and a function to say "hey, do this, show" and then go to the next step. For resume I need to update the progress bar...

Comment: You need to call `ProcessMessages` after each time you change the position of the progress bar (not just once). `ProcessMessages` will do just that - allow the application to process all current messages, including the message to update the progress bar.

Comment: Like I said: I did that.
I put the `for`, the function, `ProgressBar->Value = i, Sleep, if condition `and the `ProcessMessages()`, but no results.

Comment: Then you are not doing something right or I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. The code above works without any problems on my side and show the progressbar slowly filling from 1-100%.

Comment: Oh, ok, I tested in Windows, but did you test in the Android? In Windows it gets what I want, but Android go 0% to 100% quickly, I can't see the green thing going to 100%.

Comment: I updated my answer with your example. You haven't mention Android in your question so I didn't test it there. You need to be more specific in your question(s) to get the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I put firemonkey label to know that is for devices, but no problem... I tested your edited answer, but no results too.

Comment: ProcessMessages will not work on Android: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/924-delphi-rio-android-applicationprocessmessages-dosent-work/ I suggest you edit your question with the title such as "How to repaint the progressbar in FMX (Android)".

Comment: Did you try `progressBar1->Repaint()` yet? Personally, I would re-write this code to not block the message queue at all.  After executing the 1st step (`changeClothes(); progressBar1->Value = 20;`), I would use `TThread.(Force)Queue()` to trigger the next step (`eatSandwich(); progressBar1->Value = 40;`), and then use `TThread.(Force)Queue()` again to trigger the next step, and so on until finished.  By breaking up the steps, and letting the message queue handle pending messages in between steps, it allows the `ProgressBar` to draw itself normally, as well as keeps the UI responsive in general

Comment: Hello Remy, I tried with `Repaint()` but doesn't work. I never use `TThread`, I'm kind of new in C++ Builder. I searched on the internet, but I didn't understand how to use. Can you do a little example just to I test?